# LINQ : Join 3 datatables and add calculated field

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I've got three tables of **Datatable** type:

```
Table1: Id<Int64>, ParamX<string>;
Table2: Id<Int64>;
Table3: Id<Int64>, ParamA<double>, ParamB<Int16>;
```

I want to Join them by ID field and create Table4 with calculated field        `ParamC<double>=ParamA<double>*ParamB<Int16>`

The result should be **datatable**:

```
Table4: Id<Int64>, ParamX<string>, ParamA<double>, ParamB<Int16>, ParamC<double>
```

Is it possible to make it in single LINQ query?
madace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create or fill tables in a LINQ query, a query is not supposed to cause side-effects. You can prepare the data you want to insert into the new table with LINQ:

```
var query = from r1 in Table1.AsEnumerable()
            join r2 in Table2.AsEnumerable()
            on r1.Field<long>("ID") equals r2.Field<long>("ID")
            join r3 in Table3.AsEnumerable()
            on r2.Field<long>("ID") equals r3.Field<long>("ID")
            select new {
                ID = r1.Field<long>("ID"),
                ParamX = r1.Field<string>("ParamX"),
                ParamA = r3.Field<double>("ParamA"),
                ParamB = r3.Field<short>("ParamB"),
                ParamC = r3.Field<double>("ParamA") * r3.Field<short>("ParamB")
            };

var Table4 = new DataTable();
Table4.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(long));
Table4.Columns.Add("ParamX", typeof(string));
Table4.Columns.Add("ParamA", typeof(double));
Table4.Columns.Add("ParamB", typeof(short));
Table4.Columns.Add("ParamC", typeof(double));
```

You use a loop to execute the query and to insert the rows into the table:

```
foreach (var x in query)
{
    DataRow addedRow = Table4.Rows.Add();
    addedRow.SetField("ID", x.ID);
    addedRow.SetField("ParamX", x.ParamX);
    addedRow.SetField("ParamA", x.ParamA);
    addedRow.SetField("ParamB", x.ParamB);
    addedRow.SetField("ParamC", x.ParamC);
}
```

---

For what it's worth, here's an extension method that allows to create a `DataTable` from an `IEnumerable<anything>` via reflection:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection props =
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
        {
            PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
        }
        object[] values = new object[props.Count];
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
            }
            table.Rows.Add(values);
        }
        return table;
    }
}
```

Then you don't need to create or fill the table manually:

```
DataTable Table4 = query.ToDataTable();
```

Comment: Thank You very much for the complete and clear answer!